ServerPlayer.openMenu() не принимает параметр "pos"
Хочу в своём моде сделать BlockEntity при нажатии на который будет открываться меню
но на данном моменте у меня случается ошибка. ServerPlayer.openMenu() не принимает параметр pоs. Но без него меню просто не открывается (прилагаю консоль под номером 2.)
1.
@Override
    public @NotNull InteractionResult use(@NotNull BlockState state, @NotNull Level level, @NotNull BlockPos pos, @NotNull Player player, @NotNull InteractionHand hand, @NotNull BlockHitResult hitResult) {
        BlockEntity be = level.getBlockEntity(pos);
        if (!(be instanceof BrewBarrelEntity blockEntity))
            return InteractionResult.PASS;

        if (level.isClientSide())
            return InteractionResult.SUCCESS;

        // open screen
        if(player instanceof ServerPlayer sPlayer) {
            sPlayer.openMenu(blockEntity, pos);
        }

        return InteractionResult.CONSUME;
    }




[20:48:18] [Render thread/ERROR] [minecraft/BlockableEventLoop]: Error executing task on Client
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "net.minecraft.network.FriendlyByteBuf.readBlockPos()" because "additionalData" is null
    at com.legomanchik.slavic_delight.menu.BrewBarrelMenu.<init>(BrewBarrelMenu.java:24) ~[main/:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraftforge.network.IContainerFactory.create(IContainerFactory.java:20) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.3.0_mapped_official_1.20.1-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraft.world.inventory.MenuType.create(MenuType.java:55) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.3.0_mapped_official_1.20.1-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B}
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.screens.MenuScreens$ScreenConstructor.fromPacket(MenuScreens.java:115) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.3.0_mapped_official_1.20.1-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.screens.MenuScreens.lambda$create$0(MenuScreens.java:43) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.3.0_mapped_official_1.20.1-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178) ~[?:?] {}
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.screens.MenuScreens.create(MenuScreens.java:43) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.3.0_mapped_official_1.20.1-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.multiplayer.ClientPacketListener.handleOpenScreen(ClientPacketListener.java:1118) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.3.0_mapped_official_1.20.1-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.network.protocol.game.ClientboundOpenScreenPacket.handle(ClientboundOpenScreenPacket.java:34) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.3.0_mapped_official_1.20.1-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraft.network.protocol.game.ClientboundOpenScreenPacket.handle(ClientboundOpenScreenPacket.java:10) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.3.0_mapped_official_1.20.1-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraft.network.protocol.PacketUtils.lambda$ensureRunningOnSameThread$0(PacketUtils.java:22) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.3.0_mapped_official_1.20.1-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraft.util.thread.BlockableEventLoop.doRunTask(BlockableEventLoop.java:143) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.3.0_mapped_official_1.20.1-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B}
    at net.minecraft.util.thread.ReentrantBlockableEventLoop.doRunTask(ReentrantBlockableEventLoop.java:22) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.3.0_mapped_official_1.20.1-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading}
    at net.minecraft.util.thread.BlockableEventLoop.pollTask(BlockableEventLoop.java:116) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.3.0_mapped_official_1.20.1-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B}
    at net.minecraft.util.thread.BlockableEventLoop.runAllTasks(BlockableEventLoop.java:104) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.3.0_mapped_official_1.20.1-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.runTick(Minecraft.java:1106) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.3.0_mapped_official_1.20.1-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:718) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.3.0_mapped_official_1.20.1-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:218) ~[forge-1.20.1-47.3.0_mapped_official_1.20.1-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?] {}
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?] {}
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?] {}
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.targets.CommonLaunchHandler.runTarget(CommonLaunchHandler.java:111) ~[fmlloader-1.20.1-47.3.0.jar:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.targets.CommonLaunchHandler.clientService(CommonLaunchHandler.java:99) ~[fmlloader-1.20.1-47.3.0.jar:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.targets.ForgeClientUserdevLaunchHandler.devService(ForgeClientUserdevLaunchHandler.java:19) ~[fmlloader-1.20.1-47.3.0.jar:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.targets.CommonDevLaunchHandler.lambda$makeService$7(CommonDevLaunchHandler.java:135) ~[fmlloader-1.20.1-47.3.0.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.launch(LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.java:30) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:53) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:71) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:108) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:78) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.BootstrapLaunchConsumer.accept(BootstrapLaunchConsumer.java:26) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.BootstrapLaunchConsumer.accept(BootstrapLaunchConsumer.java:23) ~[modlauncher-10.0.9.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.bootstraplauncher.BootstrapLauncher.main(BootstrapLauncher.java:141) ~[bootstraplauncher-1.1.2.jar:?] {}

А в случае если всё таки указать параметр "pos", то игра просто не запустится и выдаст вот такую ошибку
C:\Users\Lesha\Downloads\Slavic delight\src\main\java\com\legomanchik\slavic_delight\block\custom\BrewBarrelBlock.java:89: error: method openMenu in class ServerPlayer cannot be applied to given types;
            sPlayer.openMenu(blockEntity, pos);
                   ^
  required: MenuProvider
  found:    BrewBarrelEntity,@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull BlockPos
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length


Этот вопрос похож на: Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?. Если вы считаете его другим, пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, чётко обозначив отличие и/или почему ответы на вопрос не помогли в вашем случае.

Ура, разобрался сам спустя полчаса после того, как задал вопрос.
Вот решение проблемы для тех, кто столкнулся с такой же проблемой:
@Override
    public @NotNull InteractionResult use(@NotNull BlockState state, @NotNull Level level, @NotNull BlockPos pos, @NotNull Player player, @NotNull InteractionHand hand, @NotNull BlockHitResult hitResult) {
        BlockEntity be = level.getBlockEntity(pos);
        if (!(be instanceof BrewBarrelEntity blockEntity))
            return InteractionResult.PASS;

        if (level.isClientSide())
            return InteractionResult.SUCCESS;

        // open screen
        if(player instanceof ServerPlayer sPlayer) {
            NetworkHooks.openScreen(sPlayer, blockEntity, pos);
        }

        return InteractionResult.CONSUME;
    }

